# Unable to set data in firestore subcollections

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

While uploading data on cloud firestore

```
    lateinit var db: DocumentReference

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("users/${mAuth.uid}")

    val items=HashMap<String,Any>()
    items["w"] = "t"
    db.set(items).addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }.addOnFailureListener{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data upload failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

works, but

```
    lateinit var db: DocumentReference

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("users/${mAuth.uid}/othercollection/otherdocument")

    val items=HashMap<String,Any>()
    items["w"] = "t"
    db.set(items).addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }.addOnFailureListener{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data upload failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

fails. ie. it prints "Data upload failed".

other method of declaring document path also fails, .collection().document().collection().document()..... also fails

Comment: Try to log the message from `addOnFailureListener`, what does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was insufficient permissions. I was using security rules from my old project which were not defined for nested documents. Problem resolved after changing that.

For someone else' reference, always take care while changing your project apps or adding new ones, make sure you check resources so that they are applicable on new applications linked to your project.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, the most common operation that you need to do is to log the message that comes from `addOnFailureListener` which tells you what is all about. Most likely is a problem related to insufficient permissions. To solve this, please set the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) that correspond with the queries that you are performing.